# What should we return when pattern matching on a Path constructor?

Tags: homotopy-type-theory, cubical-type-theory, higher-inductive-types

Context: Cubical Type Theory

Consider a simple HIT, say, an `HitInt`:

```
data HitInt : Set where
  pos : (n : ℕ) → HitInt
  neg : (n : ℕ) → HitInt
  posneg : pos 0 ≡ neg 0
```

Or, if you don't speak Agda we can use cubicaltt:

```
data int = pos (n : nat)
         | neg (n : nat)
         | zeroP <i> [ (i = 0) -> pos zero
                     , (i = 1) -> neg zero ]
```

We want to define, for instance, a `succ` operation for it. As a functional programmer, we want to pattern matching on this HIT. In Agda, it's:

```
sucHitInt : HitInt → HitInt
sucHitInt (pos n) = pos (suc n)
sucHitInt (neg zero) = pos 1
sucHitInt (neg (suc n)) = neg n
sucHitInt (posneg x) = pos 1
```

Or in cubicaltt:

```
sucInt : int -> int = split
  pos n -> pos (suc n)
  neg n -> sucNat n
    where sucNat : nat -> int = split
            zero -> pos one
            suc n -> neg n
  zeroP @ i -> pos one
```

What I'm interested in is the last case-split of these two pattern matchings. The function is supposed to return the successor of the input integer, but we need to implement something that "finds the successor of the input *Path*".

My question is, how are we supposed to implement this case-split? In the cubicaltt version (taken from the cubicaltt's GitHub repository, examples/integer.ctt), it matches the Path `pos 0 == neg 0` and returns `pos 1` -- say, matches a `Path`, but returns a normal integer. Is this really what we want to do? Why it's not returning a `Path` like `<i> pos 1` (even this is not a member of the higher inductive family)?

What's interesting is that, in Agda it'll fill `pos 1` in the case body when I use Agda's proof-search.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> it matches the `Path pos 0 == neg 0` and returns `pos 1` -- say, matches a Path, but returns a normal integer

My understanding is that it matches *points of path* rather than path itself. This is why the matching is on `posneg x` (where `x : I`) rather than `posneg` itself.

Since paths can be seen as (special) maps from `I`, we can think of HIT constructors as just a special of regular constructors, i.e.

```
  posneg : I ↝ HitInt [i0 ↦ pos 0 ; i1 ↦ neg 0]
```

where if you ignore "special" properties of `Interval`, it looks like a regular constructor (in cubicaltt notation it already looks similar except that `I` is always treated specially).

> What's interesting is that, in Agda it'll fill pos 1 in the case body when I use Agda's proof-search.

It's the only way to satisfy constraints imposed by previous definitions (this works for both zero cases). In fact, Agda can correctly solve even two holes (in right order):

```
sucHitInt : HitInt → HitInt
sucHitInt (pos n) = pos (suc n)
sucHitInt (posneg i) = {!!}
sucHitInt (neg zero) = {!!}
sucHitInt (neg (suc n)) = neg n
```

> Why it's not returning a Path like  pos 1 (even this is not a member of the higher inductive family)?

Again, since we're matching on points rather than paths; for symmetry it's possible to imagine that case as equal to:

```
sucHitInt (posneg i) = (λ _ → pos 1) i
```

reading somewhat like "for all projections from `I` at `i` to path `posneg` we have projections from `I` at I to constant path `(λ _ → pos 1)`". This doesn't quite work in Agda (because typecheking lambda application directly isn't very well supported), however the following (with the same meaning) does:

```
sucHitInt (posneg i) = refl {x = pos 1} i
```

Finally, abusing notation, we could rewrite that as

```
(ap sucHitInt posneg) i = (refl {x = pos 1}) i
```

(where `ap` (from the HoTT book) corresponds to `cong` in typical Agda) and, getting rid of `i` from the both sides, recover path to path mapping.

PS: i'm new to cubical myself, so hopefully someone can correct or extend my answer

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out the interval parameter in the Path constructor! This is very helpful!

Comment: By the way, is `↦` and `↝` used generally as you use them (for path endpoints and abstraction) in type theory?

Comment: @ice1000
I chose `↝` just as a fancy arrow, i don't know if it was used as such. As for `↦`, it's quite commonly used in lambdas and i think i've seen it in such context as well